# Local time and location not displaying

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created a script that is supposed to show the person browsing the website their local time, location and temperature at that location.

I have built the program in JavaScript and it seemed to work fine the other day, but somehow my code has broken. I am only able to see the p tag displaying the "Current Local Time:".

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var cityOut = document.getElementById('city');
  fetch('http://ip-api.com/json/')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(response => {
      cityOut.innerHTML = response.city + ', ' + response.country;
    })
    .catch((data, status) => {
      console.log('Request failed');
    })

  var fpsOut = document.getElementById('fps');
  setInterval(function() {
    var d = new Date();
    fpsOut.innerHTML = d.getHours() + ':' + d.getMinutes() + ':' + d.getSeconds();
  }, 1000);​
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success);
});​
function success(pos) {
  var weather = document.getElementById('weather');
  var crd = pos.coords;​
  console.log(`Latitude : ${crd.latitude}`);
  console.log(`Longitude: ${crd.longitude}`);
  fetch('https://fcc-weather-api.glitch.me/api/current?lat=' + crd.latitude + '&lon=' + crd.longitude)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(response => {
      weather.innerHTML = response.main.temp;
    })
    .catch((data, status) => {
      console.log('Request failed');
    })
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace
}

p {
  display: inline;
}

#fps {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstimezonedetect/1.0.4/jstz.min.js"></script>
<p>Current Local Time:</p>
<div id="fps"></div>
<div id="city"></div>
<div id="weather"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you debug with developer tools, what that API call returns?

Comment: It's just a typo, I can see red dots (three in all) in stack snippet. After removing them, it works.

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be some hidden characters in line 38, 41 and 45. Please delete those empty lines. It works.

Check below screenshot and remove the "."

[image]

Comment: It seems as if my code was filled with errors after I copied it over to my laptop. I have tried it on my PC and it works absolutely fine. However, when I make it into a .php file, I seem to have the same problem again.

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove 3 invalid ZERO WIDTH SPACE characters (https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200b/index.htm)
2. Change to https
3. Get an API key
4. Add error handling to the geo

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var cityOut = document.getElementById('city');
  fetch('https://ip-api.com/json/')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response)
      cityOut.innerHTML = response.city + ', ' + response.country;
    })
    .catch((data, status) => {
      console.log('Request failed');
    })
  var fpsOut = document.getElementById('fps');
  setInterval(function() {
    var d = new Date();
    fpsOut.innerHTML = d.getHours() + ':' + d.getMinutes() + ':' + d.getSeconds();
  }, 1000);
  const geo = navigator.geolocation; 
  if (geo) geo.getCurrentPosition(success,error);
});

function error(err) {
  console.warn(`ERROR(${err.code}): ${err.message}`);
}
function success(pos) {
  console.log(pos)
  var weather = document.getElementById('weather');
  var crd = pos.coords;
  console.log(`Latitude : ${crd.latitude}`);
  console.log(`Longitude: ${crd.longitude}`);
  fetch('https://fcc-weather-api.glitch.me/api/current?lat=' + crd.latitude + '&lon=' + crd.longitude)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(response => {
      weather.innerHTML = response.main.temp;
    })
    .catch((data, status) => {
      console.log('Request failed');
    })
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace
}

p {
  display: inline;
}

#fps {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstimezonedetect/1.0.4/jstz.min.js"></script>
<p>Current Local Time:</p>
<div id="fps"></div>
<div id="city"></div>
<div id="weather"></div>
```